# Cancelling a Task.Delay(...) call does not continue with the TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I expected the following code to print "Cancelled":

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Proc(cts.Token), cts.Token);
    task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Completed"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Cancelled"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
    task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Faulted"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    cts.Cancel();

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void Proc(CancellationToken token)
{
    // do some CPU-intensive work
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    Task.Delay(2000, token).Wait();
    // do some CPU-intensive work
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

It prints "Faulted", which raises these questions:

1. Why does this print "Faulted" instead of "Cancelled"?
2. Am I misusing Task.Delay(...) as a cancellable version of Thread.Sleep(...)?
3. What is the right way to Sleep/Delay and still respond to cts.Cancel()?

Comment: I was intentionally and artificially not using async/await for the purpose of understanding how the TPL works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're indeed misusing `Task.Delay()` as a cancel-able version of `Thread.Sleep()` with this code:

```
Task.Delay(2000, token).Wait();
```

It blocks the pool thread, which you're starting with `Task.Factory.StartNew` only to simulate `Thread.Sleep()`. This thread could otherwise be doing some useful job for other tasks.

Your `Main` could simply be rewritten like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var task = Task.Delay(2000, cts.Token);
    task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Completed"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Cancelled"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
    task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Faulted"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    cts.Cancel();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

In case you do need a separate thread for some CPU-bound work, you still can use `Task.Delay` inside it without blocking the thread. The loop will continue on another pool thread after `await Task.Delay(...)`. For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cts.Token;

    var task = Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        var i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            Console.WriteLine(CalcPrimeNumber(i++));
            await Task.Delay(200, token); 
        }
    }, token);

    task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Completed"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Cancelled"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
    task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Faulted"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    cts.Cancel();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

With TPL and `async/await`, you'd rarely need to use `Thread.Sleep` at all, other than for testing.

Comment: I added two small code comments to the original post to clarify that the idea is that Proc does other work besides just call Task.Delay.

Comment: You are correct. Without async/await, my code ties up a threadpool thread. As best I can tell, relying on the compiler-generated async/await code is the only correct (or at least easy) way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best answers that I can give.

1. It prints "Faulted" because Task.Delay(...) is creating a new Task. When that child task is cancelled, it propagates up as an AggregateException, not an OperationCanceledException.
2. Task.Delay(...) can be used as a cancellable-version of Thread.Sleep(...)
3. The following modification works as expected:

Modification:

```
static void Proc(CancellationToken token)
{
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    try
    {
        Task.Delay(2000, token).Wait();
    }
    catch
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        throw;
    }
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

Comment: “it propagates up as an AggregateException” Yes, but that's because you're using `Wait()`. If you used `await` instead, it would propagate as `OperationCanceledException`.

Comment: @svick Thank you! I was kinda working under an artificial constraint of not using async/await. It appears that, without reproducing some of the compiler-generated async/await/IAsyncStateMachine code, there is no straight-forward way.